# 'ORDER BY' in JPQL-query adds 'CROSS JOIN' to produced sql thus reducing final results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

I’m to create query with ordering by field of related entity, like this:

```sql
SELECT p FROM Patient p ORDER BY p.doctor.name
```

And sql-query that Hibernate builds based on that of JPQL uses CROSS JOIN with condition (effectively, inner join):

```sql
select patient0_.id as id1_1_, patient0_.doctor_id as doctor_i3_1_, patient0_.name as name2_1_
from patient patient0_ cross join doctor doctor1_
where patient0_.doctor_id=doctor1_.id
order by doctor1_.name
```

As a side-effect, all patients with nulls in ‘doctor’ field are excluded from result set. Is there any option I can switch to hint Hibernate to use LEFT JOIN in such cases? Can’t such a behavior be considered a bug? From common sense’ point, just adding ordering shoud not affect result count.

Example is intentionally simplified. In real world it’s a dynamically built criteria-query with variable set of filters and sortings. So I can not work it around and use explicit LEFT JOIN in JPQL.

I reproduced behavior of simplified example in version 5.3.9.Final and in latest 5.4.15.Final.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use explicit join instead of hibernate implicit join.

```
SELECT p FROM Patient p left join fetch p.doctor d ORDER BY d.name
```

If there is **lazy relation** and it is not wanted that doctor is loaded, **fetch** should not be used.

```
SELECT p FROM Patient p left join p.doctor d ORDER BY d.name
```

Comment: In real system things are more complicated. I use criteria builder to construct dynamic query. The ORDER BY expression is dynamic too, it comes from REST API layer, and is not predefined. So, I can not use explicit joins.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the implicit join is defined for JPA, as an inner join. So if you want to use left join semantics, you will have to use a an explicit left join.

If you want something more dynamic, I can recommend you take a look at a query builder like [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) that has left join semantics for implicit joins.

Here is a Spring WebMvc example application that supports dynamic filtering and sorting for paginated datatables: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/tree/master/examples/spring-data-webmvc